# What does ~ mean in perl?

Tags: perl

Array

```
my @ar = qw(one two);
print ~@ar,"\n";
#output 18446744073709551613
```

Scalar (Result is very interesting )

```
my $ar = "qw(onetwo)"; 
print ~$ar
#Output Please refer the screen shot.
```

My question is what `~` does?

For array it is giving the some numbers.

For scalar it is giving the some other characters, we I copied the character from terminal and pasted in `gedit`, the result is after the long spaces characters printed with revers order. I can't delete the characters from last. If I'm trying to delete the spaces,characters are delete one by one(left to right). I can't understand what is going here.?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. You would be much better off piping the output through `xxd` or `od` to see the actual bytes printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unary `~` performs bitwise negation. Numbers are first converted to integers by discarding the fractional part, then each bit in the binary representation is flipped. So on a 64-bit system, you'll get:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%x\n", ~0'
ffffffffffffffff
```

Double negation can be used to convert non-negative numbers to integers in a terse but unreadable way:

```
$ perl -le 'print ~~1.8'
1
```

Evaluated in scalar context, an array yields the number of elements, so for a two-element array, `~@a` is equivalent to `~2`.

When operating on strings, each bit in the binary representation of the string is flipped:

```
$ perl -le 'print unpack("B*", "A"), "\n", unpack("B*", ~"A")'
01000001
10111110

$ perl -le 'print unpack("H*", "onetwo"), "\n", unpack("H*", ~"onetwo")'
6f6e6574776f
90919a8b8890
```

`6f` is the hex ASCII code for `o` and `90` is the negated hex value. Since the MSB of each byte is flipped, you typically get garbage when printing the bitwise negation of a string.

Comment: Double `~~` can also be used to impose scalar context, e.g., `perl -e 'print ~~localtime'`

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators):

> Symbolic Unary Operators
>
> [...]
>   Unary "~" performs bitwise negation, that is, 1's complement. For example, 0666 & ~027 is 0640.
>   [...]

Albeit it looks different, I assume `~@ar` does a bitwise negation of the number of elements in `@ar`:

```
print ~2, "\n";
18446744073709551613
```

Comment: `~` imposes scalar context on its argument (just like, say, `+` does). That's why it ends up operating on the number of elements in `@ar`. Note the difference between that and `perl -e "print ~(9,8)"`

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [perldoc manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

> Unary "`~`" performs bitwise negation, that is, 1's complement. For example, 0666 & ~027 is 0640.

However, the `~` operator has a bunch of other functions as well, for example the `=~` operator is for applying a regular expression to a scalar.

In general, working with operators is a pretty messy ordeal, I suggest you consult the linked manpage if you have a question about them.